# nowJS on Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, nowjs-sockets

I succeeded making a small chat application with nodeJS & nowJS. It works perfect on my local machine.

Now I want to host the chat app on Windows Azure. I already got a nodeJS server working on my Windows Azure account, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[Error: Unable to load shared library C:\DWASFiles\Sites\ben-goevaerts\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\now\node_modules\node-proxy\build\Release\nodeproxy.node]
```

Assuming nowJS or socket.io aren't correctly installed. (?)
I can't find any documentation about nowJS & windows Azure.

Thanks!

Complete error: (just in case)

```
[Error: Unable to load shared library C:\DWASFiles\Sites\ben-    goevaerts\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\now\node_modules\node-proxy\build\Release\nodeproxy.node]
 Error: Unable to load shared library C:\DWASFiles\Sites\ben-goevaerts\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\now\node_modules\node-proxy\build\Release\nodeproxy.node
at Object..node (module.js:472:11)
at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (module.js:370:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\ben-goevaerts\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\now\node_modules\node-proxy\lib\node-proxy.js:1:90)
at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
 { [Error: listen EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'listen' }
```

Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:771:26)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
GetConsoleTitleW: The operation completed successfully.

Comment: now.js needs the C++ Runtime and I could see this happening if it weren't there, but I deployed, and it ran and I could see the C++ runtime was installed. (via Control Panel->Programs).  If you set up Remote Desktop can you confirm that the C++ runtime was installed as part of your deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the error "Unable to load shared library" means, but the EACCESS error could mean you're listening on an unavailable port.

This can happen when you use some custom port on your local machine and forget to change it when you deploy to Azure. Check your code and your config files to figure out which port you're using.